# When and why did Bat-Man become Batman?

Tags: dc, batman, names

I was inspired by [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105091/when-did-the-batman-become-batman) to ask a question I've had for a while:

It what issue(s) did Batman first lose the hyphen in his name? Have any of the writers stated why they changed the spelling?

Comment: The "when" is in the first story, *Detective Comics* No. 27, itself --- the cover has "The Batman" and the interior has "The Bat-man".  As to why they settled on "Batman" with no hyphen, some digging will have to be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## When: Immediately

Batman started off as "The Bat-Man" and "The Batman", *simultaneously*.

The cover of *Detective Comics* No. 27 (which contained the first Batman story, "The Case of the Chemical Syndicate") says **THE BATMAN** while the interior says **THE BAT-MAN:**

[image]
[image]

By April 1940, Batman had his own comic, the eponymous *Batman*, with no hyphen in the title:

[image]

## Why : Consistency with Other DC Properties (Presumably)

Superman was introduced in *Action Comics* No. 1 as "Superman" with no hyphen:

[image]

Given Superman's rapidly ascending popularity, followed quickly by the introduction of popular DC hero Aquaman (*More Fun Comics* No. 73, 1941), it makes sense for DC to have consolidated its hero names as single words with no hyphens, using Superman as a model especially.

Of course, Wonder Woman has always been two words (mainly because "Wonderwoman" looks awkward), but it's worth noting that her name lacks hyphenation.  Given that she was also introduced in 1941, this lends further support to DC galvanzing its naming strategy in the early 1940s, at least as far as their main heroes were concerned.

Comment: The April 1940 issue looks like it's using batmans face as a separator :)