# Batman or 'the Batman'?

Tags: dc, batman, etymology

Batman has tended to introduce himself as simply 'Batman', e.g. In the Keaton movie we had the line 
"Who are you?!"
"I'm Batman"

However he is also referred to as 'the Batman'. Is there any rhyme or reason behind which form is used and when?

Comment: related, possible dupe: [When did “The Batman” become “Batman”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105091/5184)

Comment: I believe I've seen 'the batman' used very recently - From memory when the press in the film is referring to him - but not able to check right now

Comment: @Peter The phrase has certainly been revived recently. I think you might wish to ask about a specific example. The use in recent movies is one thing, but also, for instance, why did the 2004 animated series The Batman restore the definite article to Batman's name in its title? That probably has something to do with the cartoon trying to revive the style or feeling of Batman's earliest adventures.

Comment: @Peter Other examples include the 2013 animated series "Beware the Batman", the Joker's famous "we kill the Batman" speech in _The Dark Knight_, and use of "the bat of Gotham" or "the bat vigilante" in _Batman v Superman_.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. THe question it is being said to duplicate is asking when did "The Bat-man" become "Batman" in publishing history where as this question is asking more about lore and there is a semi-answer to it... but I'm not sure I can do it in a comment...